# Surveyor Gem to Render CSV - Template is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, fastercsv, surveyor-gem

I'm trying render the results of surveys from [Surveryor](https://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor) gem as a CSV file, but get a "Template is missing" error.

For example, `localhost:3000/results/user-feedback-survey-1.csv` results in:

```
Template is missing

Missing template results/show, application/show with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml], :formats=>[:csv], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in: * "/websites/surveyportal/app/views" * "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/surveyor-0.21.0/app/views"
```

Same error for `.json`. I've added `gem 'fastercsv'` to my gem file.

Is there something I'm missing? I'm using Rails 3.1.3.

Comment: have you run `bundle install`?

Comment: Do you have a file at `app/raesults/show.csv` or `.erb` or `show.[anything]` really?

Comment: I've run the `bundle install` command and the gem installed. I did not have file at `app/views/results/show.csv` or `show.csv.erb`. I added it now and don't have that error anymore. What should I add to the template for it to yield the results? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a much better way then this, but I was able to make it work with the following code, which I gleaned from a deleted version of the [Surveyor gem show.html.erb](https://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor/blob/08f7c16de29852af1b7ba5e904153768a67730e7/app/views/results/show.html.erb) file.

```
<% csvString = "id, Code, " %>
  <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <% next if question.display_order == 1 %>
    <% csvString += "[" +question.display_order.to_s + "]" + question.text.to_s + ","  %>
<% end %>
<% csvString += "\n" %>
<% @response_sets.each do |r_set| %>
<% csvString += r_set.id.to_s + "," + r_set.access_code.to_s %>
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <% next if question.display_order == 1 %>
    <% csvString += display_response(r_set,question).to_s + "," %>
<% end %>
<% csvString += "\n" %>
<% end %>
<%= csvString %>
```

I added it to the `/app/views/results/show.csv.erb` file.